# Making a libgdx textfield ignore certain characters?

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, textfield

Hi I'm stuck with a problem I don't seem able to solve regarding a TextField for libgdx. I want to ignore certain characters such as instead of writing a space in the textfield when using "shift" for a upper-case character. As of currently I've written like this.

```
accField.setTextFieldListener(new TextFieldListener() {

  public void keyTyped(TextField textField, char c)  {

        if (c == 'a') {
        //Something here that does the replacement maybe?                                


        }


}

});
```

Comment: Have you seen Textfield.TextfieldFilter? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: That looks interesting..how could I implement it in a good way?

Comment: i wrote an answer. Hope it helps you. But i have never tryed it. Please tell me if it is wrong and correct me because i also want to use this filters for my game :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I never worked with TextFieldFilters cause i am almost new to libgdx. But as much as i understood you use them like this:

```
myTextfield.setTextFieldFilter(new TextFieldFilter() {

    // Accepts all Characters except 'a' 
    public  boolean acceptChar(TextField textField, char c) {
         if (c == 'a')
               return false;
         return true;
    }
});
```

Hope it helps. Please tell me if it works because i want to use this TextFieldFilters to :P

Comment: Cool :P Now i know that i can use them like this :P thanks :)

Comment: Regex works as well, `Character.toString(c).matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]")` to just have alphanumeric and digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use it for alphanumeric input.

```
myTextfield.setTextFieldFilter(new TextField.TextFieldFilter() {
            // Accepts all Alphanumeric Characters except
            public boolean acceptChar(TextField textField, char c) {
                if (Character.toString(c).matches("^[a-zA-Z]")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```